# How to join two table to update one in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two table user_table and subscription_table

user_table

```
| user_id(int)| email(varchar) | phone(int)|
------------------------------------------------
|    1       | abc@gmail.com   |   9910256256 |
|    2       | def@gmail.com   |   8856956325 |
|    3       | ghi@gmail.com   |   8745692455 |
|    4       | jkl@gmail.com   |   7852369526 |
```

subscription_table

```
    | email(varchar)            | type(varchar)| is_subscribed(boolean)
    ------------------------------------------------------------------
    |  abc@gmail.com            |   news       | true
    |  abc@gmail.com            |   video      | false
    |  def@gmail.com            |   news       | true
    |  def@gmail.com            |   video      | true
```

I have `user_id` and want to update `is_subscription`. Best wayto update `is_subscription`.

I have tried to do it with multiple query but i think that is not good.

Comment: And what is the logic for updating?

Comment: emails in subscription table is also in user table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
update subscription_table s
    set is_subscription = ?
    from user_table u
    where u.email = s.email and u.user_id= ?;
```

Note:  If you have a `user_id`, then you should be using that for foreign key relationships.  I don't understand why email would be used for this purpose.

Comment: i want to update email too by appending some text in that existing email like [abc@gmail.com----> abc-cancel@gmail.com]. Can you please guid me How can i do in this query @Gordon Linoff